Unable to icrease internal storage on AVD in android studio (macOS)
I'm using the latest version of Android Studio on macOS and have set up a Pixel 8 virtual device with API 35. Everything works fine except I can’t increase the internal storage, which is currently 8 GB. I’ve tried adjusting the storage size through Edit > Show Advanced Settings and then doing a cold reboot, but the storage size doesn’t change. My hard drive has plenty of space, so that’s not the problem.
I’ve tried restarting my mac, updating to the latest macOS and Android Studio versions, and doing multiple cold reboots. I also tried using the command line, but I’m having trouble with avdmanager. I’d rather not delete and recreate the virtual device. Even though the new storage size (currently 14 GB) appears when I click “Edit,” it doesn’t reflect on the AVD itself. How can I fix this?
